# Saving a django project in OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-3.4

I'm new to Django and have been trying to learn the framework using a course in plurlsight.
The author creates a django project in this way.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 demo
```

Now if I try to create a project and save it somewhere else like in the envs folder in my Documents directory here's what I get.

```
virtualenv -p /Documents/envs boardgames
The executable /Documents/envs (from --python=/Documents/envs) does not exist
```

So does this mean I have to keep all my django projects inside /usr/local/bin/python3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-p` flag tells virtualenv to use a different executable for python instead of installing a brand new copy in `demo`. So obviously that folder must exist and have python executable in it (`usr/local/bin/python3` in this case).

What you want to do is use `virtualenv demo`. This will create a folder with a python distribution in `demo` in the current folder. You then create your project in the current folder.

Comment: Can I locate this demo folder inside Documents or for that matter anywhere else in my computer?

Comment: It can be anywhere, but a good idea is to have one folder per project. That way your copy of python is specific to your project, along with dependencies etc. Other projects can have their own copies of python and other dependencies.